# Autohotkey layout independent "Input". Wait for any key. "Input" alternatives

Tags: input, autohotkey

Here goes part of my script:

```
~LWin Up::
  Input, key, L1
  if (key = "n") {
    Run, Notepad.exe
  }
  else if (key = "s") {
    Run, cmd.exe
  }      
return
```

After releasing LWin it waits for another key to be pressed, then runs application corresponding to the key. Тhe problem is that if I switch to russian layout 's' turns to 'ы' and the script won't work.

How do I make it layout independent? Duplicating the code for 'ы' isn't the option.

The solution might be something like this:

```
#n::
#s::
  stringsplit, splitted_, A_ThisHotkey
  key := splitted_2
  if (key = "n") {
    Run, Notepad.exe
  }
  else if (key = "s") {
    Run, cmd.exe
  }
  Send {LWin up} ; release LWin
return

~LWin Up::
  stringsplit, splitted_, A_PriorHotkey
  if (splitted_1 = "#") { ; if win+key combo has just been released
    return                ; no need to keep LWin down
  }
  Send {LWin down}        ; else keep it down
return
```

I've tried it but it doesn't work properly. Sometimes it won't release LWin, sometimes it won't keep it pressed. Plus that approach has other drawbacks so I don't want to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first script seems to work just fine with the latest Unicode version of AutoHotkey. Get latest version @ ahkscript.org

Added a check for "ы" in the code below:

```
~LWin Up::
  Input, key, L1
  if (key = "n" or key = "ы") {
    Run, Notepad.exe
  }
  else if (key = "s") {
    Run, cmd.exe
  }      
return
```

Make sure to Encode your with script UTF-8 (not UTF-8 without BOM)

Edit:

Okay I think I found an Answer that doesn't require you to Add "ы" but instead relies on SC codes produced by the Keyboard, meaning it's Layout independent.

[Relevant info from Input command from the Docs:](http://ahkscript.org/docs/commands/Input.htm)

> E [v1.1.20+]: Handle single-character end keys by character code
>   instead of by keycode. This provides more consistent results if the
>   active window's keyboard layout is different to the script's keyboard
>   layout. It also prevents key combinations which don't actually produce
>   the given end characters from ending input; for example, if @ is an
>   end key, on the US layout Shift+2 will trigger it but Ctrl+Shift+2
>   will not (if the E option is used). If the C option is also used, the
>   end character is case-sensitive.
>
> EndKeys A list of zero or more keys, any one of which terminates the
>   Input when pressed (the EndKey itself is not written to OutputVar).
>   When an Input is terminated this way, ErrorLevel is set to the word
>   EndKey followed by a colon and the name of the EndKey. Examples:
>   EndKey:., EndKey:Escape.
>
> The EndKey list uses a format similar to the Send command. For
>   example, specifying {Enter}.{Esc} would cause either ENTER, period
>   (.), or ESCAPE to terminate the Input. To use the braces themselves as
>   end keys, specify {{} and/or {}}.
>
> To use Control, Alt, or Shift as end-keys, specify the left and/or
>   right version of the key, not the neutral version. For example,
>   specify {LControl}{RControl} rather than {Control}.
>
> Although modified keys such as Control-C (^c) are not supported,
>   certain characters that require the shift key to be held down --
>   namely punctuation marks such as ?!:@&{} -- are supported in v1.0.14+.
>   Other characters are supported with the E option described above, in
>   v1.1.20+.
>
> An explicit virtual key code such as {vkFF} may also be specified.
>   This is useful in the rare case where a key has no name and produces
>   no visible character when pressed. Its virtual key code can be
>   determined by following the steps at the bottom fo the key list page.

```
~LWin Up::
  Input, key, L1 E, {SC031}.{SC01F} ; {n}.{s}
  if (Errorlevel = "EndKey:SC031") {
    Run, Notepad.exe
  }
  If (Errorlevel = "EndKey:SC01f") {
    Run, cmd.exe
  }
return
```

Also, I wasn't able to reproduce an issue where Windows key was held down?